# Length of curves with same images

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves

From a geometrically intuitive point of view, it is obvious that if two **injective** $C^1$ curves $\gamma,\delta$ with values in $\mathbb R^n$ have the same images, then their lengths $\ell(\gamma)$ and $\ell(\delta)$ (as defined by the standard definition from differential geometry) are equal. This is a well-known resulut if $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are reparametrizations of one another; however, they need not necessarily be. Can it still be proved without this assumption?

Answer (score 1):

How about 
$$
\gamma(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t)) \ \ t\in[0,2\pi]
$$
and
$$
\delta(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t)) \ \ t\in[0,4\pi]
$$
They clearly have the same image, but $\ell(\gamma)=2\pi \neq 4\pi=\ell(\delta)$.

Comment: You got me there; corrected to *injective* curve. :-)

Comment: Ok adding the injective hypothesis changes the problem. I think then your intuition is correct. Have you try to approach the problem using the arc length reparametrization? I mean that if 2 injective $C^1$ curves have the same image then they have the same arc length reparametrization and thus the same length? This of course will give that they are indeed a reparametrization one of the other.

Comment: But as far as I know, a curve as an arc length reparametrization iff it is regular. And we did not assume our curve was regular.

Comment: You are right! The derivative must not vanish to use the arc length rep. I am clueless, if something occurs to me I'll certainly post it